# AJAX doesn't send post data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I have this problem where i cant get any response from the .php that ajax is sending data to.
its supposed to run a insert on mysql, i tried putting the query manually to see if it works and it does.

**Here's the function that sends ajax**

```
function Continue(SLAatendida) {
var url = window.location.pathname;
var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+ 1);
    console.log(SLAatendida);
    console.log(id);
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ws.php',
    data: { 
        'id': id,
        'sla_atendida': SLAatendida
    },
    success: function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
    }
    });
```

**And the php file thats supposed to run the query (ws.php)**

```
    <?php
session_start();

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

include('debug.php');
include('../antest/dbconnect.php');

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$debug_to_console("ws");

$id = $_POST["id"];
$SLAatendida = $_POST["sla_atendida"];

$sql_upd_sla = "INSERT INTO sla (id, sla_atendida) VALUES ('$id','$SLAatendida')";
$data = $conn->query($sql_upd_sla);
if($conn->query($sql_upd_sla))
{
    echo "Registro efetuado com sucesso";
} else {
    echo "Houve um erro";
    die();
}
?>
```

Both console.log returns the right values from the var.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't sending it? Check the Network tab of your Developer Console when you submit, and look at the Request tab to see what's there. Also do `var_dump($_POST);` in your PHP to see what it contains. If everything is there, `echo $sql_upd_sla;` to see what that contains.

Comment: @aynber Yeah, i was wrong about not sending it, checked the network tab and ws.php is there, however both `var_dump` and `echo` tries doesnt return any value, also i noticed that the `console.log(msg)` returns all the code from the page, is that supposed to happen?

Comment: Nope. It should be returning a message, not the code. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page

Comment: yeah i ran all the checks and php is installed correctly, even tho i'm using 7.2 and yeah, not using short tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the URL attribute you must put the http://localhost or the url your have configure in your local machine + ws.php

example:

```
url: 'http://localhost/ws.php',
```

Comment: oh so that was the problem, thanks a lot for your help!